# How would I modify this code so that I can use it to iterate and test through a list of errors?

Tags: perl, unit-testing

This is just an example of one of the tests I run on an error. I want to edit this so that I can loop through a list of errors. Would I put these errors in to a hash and create a for loop to iterate through them. I'm not sure exactly how it's done.
I will display the test and the error library below. Just need a small example to get me going.

Test file:

```
use lib('./t/lib/');
use Test::More tests => 3;
use ASC::Builder:Error;
#########################################################################################################
##############  test for new() method in Error.pm - Test Case: HASH  ####################################
#########################################################################################################



# error hash
my $error_hash = UNABLE_TO_PING_SWITCH_ERROR;

# error hash is passed into new and an error object is outputted
my $error_in = ASC::Builder::Error->new($error_hash);

# checks to see if the output object from new is an Error object
isa_ok($error_in, 'ASC::Builder::Error');

# checking that object can call the message() method
can_ok( $error_in, 'message');


# checks to see if the output message matches the message contained in the error hash(correct)
is($error_in->message(),( $error_hash->{message} ), 'Returns correct error message');
```

ErrorLibrary.pm

```
package ASC::Builder::ErrorLibrary;

use strict;
use warnings;
use parent 'Exporter';

# list of export error messages
our @EXPORT_OK = qw/

INCORRECT_CABLING_ERROR
UPDATE_IMAGE_ERROR
UNABLE_TO_PING_SWITCH_ERROR
/;  

# error message list

use constant {
    # wiki link included as a variable in this example
    INCORRECT_CABLING_ERROR => {
        code => "INCORRECT_CABLING_ERROR",
        errorNum => 561,
        category => 'Cabling Error',
        message => "ToR cabling is not correct at T1.The uplinks must be cabled to exactly one t1 device group",
        tt => { template => 'disabled'},
        fatal => 1,
        wiki_page =>'http://w.server-build.com/index.phpBuilder/ErrorCodes/INCORRECT_CABLING_ERROR',
    },

    UPDATE_IMAGE_ERROR => {
        code => "UPDATE_IMAGE_ERROR",
        errorNum => 556,
        category => 'Switch Error',
        message => "Cannot determine switch model",
        tt => { template => 'disabled'},
        fatal => 1,
        wiki_page =>'http://www.server-build.com/index.php/NetMgmt/Builder/ErrorCodes/UPDATE_IMAGE_ERROR',
    },

    UNABLE_TO_PING_SWITCH_ERROR => {
        code => "UNABLE_TO_PING_SWITCH_ERROR",
        errorNum => 727,
        category => 'Switch Error',
        message => "Could not ping switch [% switch_ip %] in [% timeout %] seconds.",
        tt => {template => 'disabled'},
        fatal => 1,
        wiki_page => 'http://www.server-build.com/index.php/Builder/ErrorCodes/UNABLE_TO_PING_SWITCH_ERROR',
    },

    UNKNOWN_CLIENT_CERT_ID_ERROR => {
        code => "UNKNOWN_CLIENT_CERT_ID_ERROR",
        errorNum => 681,
        category => 'Services Error',
        message => "Unknown client certificate id: [% cert_id %]",
        tt => { template => 'disabled'},
        fatal => 1,
        wiki_page =>'http://www.server-build.com/index.php/Builder/ErrorCodes/UNKNOWN_CLIENT_CERT_ID_ERROR',
    },


# add errors to this library    
};


1;
```

I'm just not sure how to create my list. should I create of a list of with input , process and outputs to test against. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Please clarify what the problem is. Are you asking how to structure the unit test to avoid code duplication? You are talking about `process`, which from your previous questions I believe is a method. Why would that go into the unit test?

Comment: No sorry, I just want to know how I can set up my test so that instead of being able to test one error, I can use a for loop or the like to run the tests on multiple errors. I didn't mean to bring the word process into it. I just thought that I should create a list with `data = [input => UNABLE_TO_PING_SWITCH_ERROR, output => "Could not ping switch 192.192.0.0 in 30 seconds];` Would it be possible to do something like that for each error, put into an array of data and loop through it

Comment: Do you get what I'm trying to do? Maybe I'm going the wrong way about it?

Comment: oh really. Why do the constants make it tricky?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110151/discussion-between-simbabque-and-paul-russell).

Comment: @simbabque I have a question/ bad news for myself regarding the help you gave me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long discussion in chat, I propose the following approach to do unit testing, as well as a light restructuring of the actual code to make things a bit easier.

**Changes I made**

I have restructured the way the code creates the error message from a template to not use [Template](http://p3rl.org/Template), as it was clear from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36771368/1331451) that it is a bit overkill.

It now uses [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) with a simple pattern like `Timeout after %s seconds`. I used `%s` throughout my examples on purpose as there is never any type checking in those, but it could of course be added. The arguments for this message are passed to the constructor as a list of key/value pairs starting from the 2nd argument.

```
my $e = Error->new(CONSTANT, foo => 'bar');
```

**The example ErrorLibrary**

The first argument `CONSTANT` still comes from your Error library. I have included the following simplified examples.

```
package ErrorList;
use strict;
use warnings;
use parent 'Exporter';
use constant {
    ERROR_WIFI_CABLE_TOO_SHORT => {
        category  => 'Layer 1',
        template  => 'A WiFi cable of %s meters is too short.',
        context   => [qw(length)],
        fatal     => 1,
        wiki_page => 'http://example.org',
    },
    ERROR_CABLE_HAS_WRONG_COLOR => {
        category  => 'Layer 1',
        template  => 'You cannot connect to %s using a %s cable.',
        context   => [qw(router color)],
        fatal     => 1,
        wiki_page => 'http://example.org',
    },
    ERROR_I_AM_A_TEAPOT => {
        category  => 'Layer 3',
        template  => 'The device at %s is a teapot.',
        context   => [qw(ip)],
        fatal     => 0,
        wiki_page => 'http://example.org',
    },
};

our @EXPORT = qw(
    ERROR_WIFI_CABLE_TOO_SHORT
    ERROR_CABLE_HAS_WRONG_COLOR
    ERROR_I_AM_A_TEAPOT
);

our @EXPORT_OK = qw(ERROR_WIFI_CABLE_TOO_SHORT);
```

The *context* is an array reference with a list of keys that are expected at construction.

**The refactored (simplified) Error class**

This class includes POD to explain what it does. The important methods are the constructor, `message` and `stringify`.

```
package Error;
use strict;
use warnings;

=head1 NAME

Error - A handy error class

=head1 SYNOPSIS

use Error;
use ErrorList 'ERROR_WIFI_CABLE_TOO_SHORT';

    my $e = Error->new(
        ERROR_WIFI_CABLE_TOO_SHORT,
        timeout   => 30,
        switch_ip => '127.0.0.1'
    );
    die $e->stringify;

=head1 DESCRIPTION

This class can create objects from a template and stringify them into a
log-compatible pattern. It makes sense to use it together
with L<ErrorList>.


=head1 METHODS

=head2 new($error, %args)

The constructor takes the error definition and a list of key/value pairs
with context information as its arguments.

...

=cut

sub new {
    my ( $class, $error, %args ) = @_;

    # initialize with the error data
    my $self = $error;

    # check required arguments...
    foreach my $key ( @{ $self->{context} } ) {
        die "$key is required" unless exists $args{$key};

        # ... and take the ones we need
        $self->{args}->{$key} = $args{$key};    # this could have a setter
    }

    return bless $self, $class;
}

=head2 category

This is the accessor for the category.

=cut

sub category {
    return $_[0]->{category};
}

=head2 template

This is the accessor for the template.

=cut

sub template {
    return $_[0]->{template};
}

=head2 fatal

This is the accessor for whether the error is fatal.

=cut

sub is_fatal {
    return $_[0]->{fatal};
}

=head2 wiki_page

This is the accessor for the wiki_page.

=cut

sub wiki_page {
    return $_[0]->{wiki_page};
}

=head2 context

This is the accessor for the context. The context is an array ref
of hash key names that are required as context arguments at construction.

=cut

sub context {
    return $_[0]->{context};
}

=head2 category

This is the accessor for the args. The args are a hash ref of context
arguments that are passed in as a list at construction.

=cut

sub args {
    return $_[0]->{args};
}

=head2 message

Builds the message string from the template.

=cut

sub message {
    my ($self) = @_;

    return sprintf $self->template,
        map { $self->args->{$_} } @{ $self->context };
}

=head2 stringify

Stringifies the error to a log message, including the message,
category and wiki_page.

=cut

sub stringify {
    my ($self) = @_;

    return sprintf qq{%s : %s\nMore info: %s}, $self->category,
        $self->message, $self->wiki_page;
}

=head1 AUTHOR

simbabque (some guy on StackOverflow)

=cut
```

**The actual unit tests**

Now to test this, it is important to distinguish between behavior and data. The *behavior* includes all the accessors that are defined in the code, as well the more interesting subs like `new`, `message` and `stringify`.

The first part of the test file I created for this example includes these. It creates a fake error structure `$example_error` and uses it to check that the constructor can deal with the right parameters, missing or excess parameter, that the accessors return the right stuff, and that `message` and `stringify` both create the correct content.

Remember that those tests are mainly a safety net when changing the code (especially after a few months). If you accidentally change something in the wrong place, the tests will fail.

```
package main;    # something like 01_foo.t
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;
use Test::Exception;
use LWP::Simple 'head';

subtest 'Functionality of Error' => sub {
    my $example_error = {
        category  => 'Connection Error',
        template  => 'Could not ping switch %s in %s seconds.',
        context   => [qw(switch_ip timeout)],
        fatal     => 1,
        wiki_page => 'http://example.org',
    };

    # happy case
    {
        my $e = Error->new(
            $example_error,
            timeout   => 30,
            switch_ip => '127.0.0.1'
        );
        isa_ok $e, 'Error';

        can_ok $e, 'category';
        is $e->category, 'Connection Error',
            q{... and it returns the correct value};

        can_ok $e, 'template';
        is $e->template, 'Could not ping switch %s in %s seconds.',
            q{... and it returns the correct values};

        can_ok $e, 'context';
        is_deeply $e->context, [ 'switch_ip', 'timeout' ],
            q{... and it returns the correct values};

        can_ok $e, 'is_fatal';
        ok $e->is_fatal, q{... and it returns the correct values};

        can_ok $e, 'message';
        is $e->message, 'Could not ping switch 127.0.0.1 in 30 seconds.',
            q{... and the message is correct};

        can_ok $e, 'stringify';
        is $e->stringify,
            "Connection Error : Could not ping switch 127.0.0.1 in 30 seconds.\n"
            . "More info: http://example.org",
            q{... and stringify contains the right message};
    }

    # not enough arguments
    throws_ok( sub { Error->new( $example_error, timeout => 1 ) },
        qr/switch_ip/, q{Creating without switch_ip dies} );

    # too many arguments
    lives_ok(
        sub {
            Error->new(
                $example_error,
                timeout   => 1,
                switch_ip => 2,
                foo       => 3
            );
        },
        q{Creating with too many arguments lives}
    );

};
```

There are some specific test cases missing. In case you use a metric tool like [Devel::Cover](http://p3rl.org/Devel::Cover) it is worth noting that full coverage does not mean all the possible cases are covered.

**Tests for your error data quality**

Now the second part that is worth covering in this example is the correctness of the error templates in ErrorLibrary. Someone might accidentally mix up something later, or there might be a new placeholder added to a message, but not to the context array.

The following test code would ideally be placed in its own file and only be run when you are done working on a feature, but for illustration purposes this just continues after the above code block, hence the two first-level `subtest`s.

The main part of your question was about the list of test cases. I consider this to be very important. You want your test code to be clean, easy to read and even easier to maintain. Test often doubles as documentation, and nothing is more annoying then changing code, and then trying to figure out how the tests work so you can update them. So always remember this:

## Tests are production code too!

Now let's take a look at the tests for the errors.

```
subtest 'Correctness of ErrorList' => sub {

    # these test cases contain all the errors from ErrorList
    my @test_cases = (
        {
            name => 'ERROR_WIFI_CABLE_TOO_SHORT',
            args => {
                length => 2,
            },
            message => 'A WiFi cable of 2 meters is too short.',
        },
        {
            name => 'ERROR_CABLE_HAS_WRONG_COLOR',
            args => {
                router => 'foo',
                color  => 'red',
            },
            message => 'You cannot connect to foo using a red cable.',
        },
        {
            name => 'ERROR_I_AM_A_TEAPOT',
            args => {
                ip => '127.0.0.1',
            },
            message => 'The device at 127.0.0.1 is a teapot.',
        },
    );

    # use_ok 'ErrorList'; # only use this line if you have files!
    ErrorList->import;    # because we don't have a file ErrorList.pm
                          # in the file system
    pass 'ErrorList used correctly';    # remove if you have files

    foreach my $t (@test_cases) {
        subtest $t->{name} => sub {

            # because we need to use a variable to get to a constant
            no strict 'refs';

            # create the Error object from the test data
            # will also fail if the name was not exported by ErrorList
            my $e;
            lives_ok(
                sub { $e = Error->new( &{ $t->{name} }, %{ $t->{args} } ) },
                q{Error can be created} );

            # and see if it has the right values
            is $e->message, $t->{message},
                q{... and the error message is correct};

            # use LWP::Simple to check if the wiki page link is not broken
            ok head( $e->wiki_page ), q{... and the wiki page is reachable};
        };
    }
};

done_testing;
```

It basically has an array of test cases, with one case for each of the possible error constants that get exported by ErrorLibrary. It has the name, which is used to load the right error and to identify the test case in the TAP output, the required arguments to run the test, and the expected final output. I only included *message* to keep it short.

In case an error template name gets modified in ErrorLibrary (or removed) without changing the text, the `lives_ok` around the object instantiation will fail because that name was not exported. That's a nice plus.

It will not, however, catch if a new error has been added without a test case. An approach for that would be to look at the symbol table in the `main` namespace, but that's a bit too advanced for the scope of this answer.

What it also does is use [LWP::Simple](http://p3rl.org/LWP::Simple) to do a `HEAD` HTTP request to each wiki URL to see if those are reachable. That also has the nice benefit that if you run it when making a build it acts a bit like a monitoring tool.

**Bringing it all together**

Finally, here is the TAP output, when run without `prove`.

```
    # Subtest: Functionality of Error
    ok 1 - An object of class 'Error' isa 'Error'
    ok 2 - Error->can('category')
    ok 3 - ... and it returns the correct value
    ok 4 - Error->can('template')
    ok 5 - ... and it returns the correct values
    ok 6 - Error->can('context')
    ok 7 - ... and it returns the correct values
    ok 8 - Error->can('is_fatal')
    ok 9 - ... and it returns the correct values
    ok 10 - Error->can('message')
    ok 11 - ... and the message is correct
    ok 12 - Error->can('stringify')
    ok 13 - ... and stringify contains the right message
    ok 14 - Creating without switch_ip dies
    ok 15 - Creating with too many arguments lives
    1..15
ok 1 - Functionality of Error
    # Subtest: Correctness of ErrorList
    ok 1 - ErrorList used correctly
        # Subtest: ERROR_WIFI_CABLE_TOO_SHORT
        ok 1 - Error can be created
        ok 2 - ... and the error message is correct
        ok 3 - ... and the wiki page is reachable
        1..3
    ok 2 - ERROR_WIFI_CABLE_TOO_SHORT
        # Subtest: ERROR_CABLE_HAS_WRONG_COLOR
        ok 1 - Error can be created
        ok 2 - ... and the error message is correct
        ok 3 - ... and the wiki page is reachable
        1..3
    ok 3 - ERROR_CABLE_HAS_WRONG_COLOR
        # Subtest: ERROR_I_AM_A_TEAPOT
        ok 1 - Error can be created
        ok 2 - ... and the error message is correct
        ok 3 - ... and the wiki page is reachable
        1..3
    ok 4 - ERROR_I_AM_A_TEAPOT
    1..4
ok 2 - Correctness of ErrorList
1..2
```

Comment: could we open a discussion whenever you're free? I have a few questions on the code. My funtionality test works fine, but my correctness test gives a few errors.

Comment: @PaulRussell go into the old one

Comment: I'll be online most of the time for the next few days. Thanks